# How possible to use "Email Link" button in Tor?

Tags: firefox, linux, email

In usual Firefox there is a very convenient (for me) button: Email Link. When I'm clicking it the Thunderbird activates and creates an Email with link on the page in letter body.

In the Tor clicking on "Email link" button makes nothing. 
OS Linux (LMDE2). I had placed `.thunderbird` in a tor-browser, file but it doesn't help. I also wrote in the menu 'application' way for Thunderbird: `/opt/thunderbird/thunderbird` - nothing.
Is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

By intent Tor Browser won't try to run applications on your local system when links in Tor Browser are clicked.

In cases this could lead to the user accidentally contaminating between their identity on Tor Browser and some other identity associated with another application on the system or store some long-term information on the disk that directly links it to a tor browser session, by a malicious actor inserting a "cookie" mailto: URL onto some site, that is uniquely generated per visitor. Worse still, opening the door to the possibility of making various applications handle a URI which would cause them to make network connections to attacker controlled end-points outside of the Tor proxy.

For more details on what it is designed to achieve the [Tor Browser Design Spec](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser/design/) is a worthwhile read.